# Include children

Tags: xml, xslt, wsdl, xslt-1.0

I have WSDL document and I want to print out content of all **<documentation>** tags. Now let's assume this tag can contain also some HTML tags for formatting or adding images.

I want XSLT template to do this but I only get the plain text content of the tags.

This is my XSLT template (named **my-xslt.xsl**):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/service">
<html>
<body>

<xsl:apply-templates select="documentation"/>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="documentation">
<div>documentation: <xsl:copy-of select="."/></div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now let's say I have this WSDL (it is a copy of this WSDL: http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL enhanced of strong and img HTML tags in documentation tag + added xslt style):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-xslt.xsl"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
      <s:element name="GetQuote">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="symbol" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="GetQuoteResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetQuoteResult" type="s:string" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetQuote" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetQuoteResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteHttpGetIn">
    <wsdl:part name="symbol" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteHttpGetOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteHttpPostIn">
    <wsdl:part name="symbol" type="s:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetQuoteHttpPostOut">
    <wsdl:part name="Body" element="tns:string" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="StockQuoteSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This is custom made documentation of this service <img src="test.jpg" /> <strong>strong test</strong></wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetQuoteSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetQuoteSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="StockQuoteHttpGet">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get Stock quote for a company Symbol</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetQuoteHttpGetIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetQuoteHttpGetOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:portType name="StockQuoteHttpPost">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Get Stock quote for a company Symbol</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:GetQuoteHttpPostIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:GetQuoteHttpPostOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteSoap" type="tns:StockQuoteSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteSoap12" type="tns:StockQuoteSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteHttpGet" type="tns:StockQuoteHttpGet">
    <http:binding verb="GET" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <http:operation location="/GetQuote" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <http:urlEncoded />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="StockQuoteHttpPost" type="tns:StockQuoteHttpPost">
    <http:binding verb="POST" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetQuote">
      <http:operation location="/GetQuote" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <mime:content type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <mime:mimeXml part="Body" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="StockQuote">
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuoteSoap" binding="tns:StockQuoteSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuoteSoap12" binding="tns:StockQuoteSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuoteHttpGet" binding="tns:StockQuoteHttpGet">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="StockQuoteHttpPost" binding="tns:StockQuoteHttpPost">
      <http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The resulting HTML contains only plain text without the image and "strong test" is not bolded.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show more of the WSDL document? This is most likely an issue with namespaces. The WSDL will have a namespace declaration which you are not accounting for in your XSLT. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter much. For example this one: http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?WSDL I tried it now, only added some HTML inside wsdl:documentation tag and added &lt;?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-xslt.xsl"?>. Output is without the HTML used in WSDL. A can paste it here as I adjusted it but maybe it would be waste of space?

Comment: Please post enough code that would enable us to reproduce the problem.  Do not worry about wasting space; do worry about wasting the time of people who are trying to help you.

Comment: I added the adjusted WSDL then.

Comment: There is no `<documentation>` in the posted XML code. OTOH, there **are** numerous namespace declarations that your stylesheet needs to account for when selecting/matching nodes. Therefore the result is empty and does not move us forward. I would like to see the XML source that produced the result you claim, i.e. copy of `<documentation>` without the inner HTML tags.

Comment: The result is not empty, the result is: "This is custom made documentation of this service  strong test Get Stock quote for a company Symbol Get Stock quote for a company Symbol" So THIS IS the XML that produces the result I claim. In other words, this is the XML document I am applying the style for and I want to make it work for it.

Comment: No, that's not possible. See:http://xsltransform.net/pPgCcov There must be something else in the chain.

Comment: Use the scrollbar in the result view. ;-)

Comment: But it is strange that there are no basic HTML tags at least so I guess my XSLT stylesheet IS somehow wrong. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, it does appear there. Note that these are the ONLY text nodes in the XML document. They are copied by a default template. Your stylesheet selects nothing, because it ignores the namespaces - see my answer for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your stylesheet is that it disregards the namespaces of the original XML. In order to copy the documentation elements with their inner HTML tags, try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//wsdl:documentation"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wsdl:documentation">
    <div>documentation: <xsl:copy-of select="."/></div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```